# Read information from a Google Slides link with android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, google-slides

Basically, assuming I have a link to a google slide (as provided by user), for example:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1c3TbLKMVwOqgP70l0ph2jSvIHAaZnZoSMnvW8cxs8Ik/edit?usp=sharing

Ultimately, I want to answer the following:
Is there a way to get the slides into an array of some sort of image file?
Then, is there a way to get the speaker notes into an array of Strings?

Since we have the link (assuming it is set as "Public-anyone can view"), we theoretically have access to all these information, as we can access it in the Google Slides page. However, how do we extract it algorithmically? Is there a specific place where these information is stored in the Google server where I can just retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the whole presentation in various formats:

`https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<PRESENTATION_ID>/export/<FORMAT>`

Possible formats are: `pdf`, `pptx`, `odp`, `txt` (strings only)

> e.g.
>   https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1c3TbLKMVwOqgP70l0ph2jSvIHAaZnZoSMnvW8cxs8Ik/export/pptx

To download slides as images, you have to specify a particular slide (page):
`https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/<PRESENTATION_ID>/export/<FORMAT>?pageid=<PAGE_ID>`

Possible formats are: jpeg, svg, png

> e.g.
>   https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1c3TbLKMVwOqgP70l0ph2jSvIHAaZnZoSMnvW8cxs8Ik/export/jpeg?pageid=g1f5653c4cc_0_437

You can find the page id at the end of a URL (`http://docs.google...slide=id.<PAGE_ID>`).